# returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust

This code is throwing an error about returning a reference from the function:

```
fn sha512_256_digest(str: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let x = digest::digest(&digest::SHA512_256, str);
    x.as_ref()
}
```

What would be the correct way to return the *as_ref()* value of *x* here?

Comment: "_I get why the error is being returned_" Could you quote it in your post? That could help future users find this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. That's because `digest()` returns an owned value and `as_ref()` (by definition) borrows from it. When the function returns, the memory owned by the return value of `digest()` is destroyed and the referenced returned by `as_ref()` becomes invalid.

I guess your goal is to hide the implementation detail that `digest()` returns a `GenericArray`, while you only need a `&[u8]`. You can get something similar by hiding the concrete type:

```
fn sha512_256_digest(str: &[u8]) -> impl AsRef<[u8]> {
    digest::digest(&digest::SHA512_256, str)
}
```

... should work. The function signature says that the return value will be some anonymous type which the caller can only ever know about that it can be referenced as if it was a `&[u8]`. The caller can do

```
// `d` is of some anonymous type
let d = sha512_256_digest(...);

// `db` is a &[u8]
let db = d.as_ref();
```

However, I'd recommend *not* to hide types in such a way.

Answer (score 6):

Since the value you're returning is created in (and thus owned by) the function, a reference to it **cannot** be returned as it won't exist once the function finishes.

You must either change the function to return an owned value or make its argument a mutable reference `&mut [u8]` and remove the return - so your options for function signatures would probably be one of the following:

```rust
fn sha512_256_digest(str: &mut [u8])
```

or

```rust
fn sha512_256_digest(str: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8>
```

A complete example with the former would be:

```rust
let mut x = <insert your byte array here>;
sha512_256_digest(&mut x);
<use x here>
```

A complete example with the latter would be:

```rust
let x = <insert your byte array here>;
let y = sha512_256_digest(&x);
<use y here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which hashing library you are using, but there should be a way to get the actual hash data (instead of a reference to it). Looking at your code, this will probably be a value of type `[u8; 32]`. This is the value you want to return from your function.